# Drupal VoipCall getDirection, getCallChannel, getCallNetwork

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am implementing a script using the VoIP drupal module which is posted below:

```
$call= new VoipCall();
$phone_number='phone_number';
$text="example text"
$script= new VoipScript('example');
$call->setScript($script);
$success=voip_text($text, $call);
```

However, although the text message is sent successfully, I recieve these errors:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$direction in VoipCall->getDirection() (line 415 of /home/hectorre/public_html/sites/all/modules/voipdrupal/modules/voipcall/voipcall.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$call_channel in VoipCall->getCallChannel() (line 503 of /home/hectorre/public_html/sites/all/modules/voipdrupal/modules/voipcall/voipcall.inc).
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$call_network in VoipCall->getCallNetwork() (line 523 of /home/hectorre/public_html/sites/all/modules/voipdrupal/modules/voipcall/voipcall.inc)
```

I have looked at the documentation but have been unable to find any resources which explain what these methods are and how to resolve the errors.

Answer (score 0):

Its a notice not an error. In Drupal 7 you can disable notices (recommended for production), by navigating to admin/config/development/logging and choose the radio button "None" as seen below:

[image]

Also note that you must set your destination number in call object:

```
$call= new VoipCall();
$phone_number='phone_number';
$call->setDestNumber($phone_number);
$text="example text"
$script= new VoipScript('example');
$call->setScript($script);
$success=voip_text($text, $call);
```